# Loading in Matlab an .xls file created in Stata

Tags: matlab, stata

I have the following problem:

1) consider a dataset in Stata whose variables are of type float, double, byte. Observations are all "numbers"

2) I want to save the dataset in .xls format; hence I type in Stata `export excel using ".../A.xls"`

3) When I open A.xls in Excel, the cells have format "General"

4) I want to load A.xls in Matlab but I get the error `Unreadable Excel file: XLS File contains unicode text which is not yet supported`

5) If, instead, before going to Matlab, I apply the format "Numbers" to the cells in Excel, A.xls can be easily loaded in Matlab.

Any suggestion on how going directly from Stata to Matlab in this particular case?

Comment: My guess is that you need to check if you can make Stata export in some other format than Unicode. There is not much more to that. If you can't, then matlab will have problems opening it.

Comment: Another option is to export your data as `.csv` format, easily readable by Matlab or any other softwware

Answer (score 1):

With Stata 14, you can save the file as `xlsx` instead of `xls`. In this case, the error message on OSX disappears. On Windows, `xls` seems to work fine as well.

Answer (score 0):

is the problem you having just from xlsread? did you try [readtable](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)?

Comment: Shoould I save as csv in that case? With the xls format it does not work

Comment: if you can export as csv then do that. it's far more compatible. once imported as csv into matlab it can be exported with [writetable](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html) to xls or xlsx file format.